# How can i solve This Query in (SQL)?

Tags: sql

I have Table Like which contain id,Name,Uid Like This:

```
--------------
Id  Name   Uid  |
1   Ram     0   |
2   Sham    1   |
3   Cam     1   |
4   Dam     2   | 
5   Eam     3   | 
6   Fam     4   |
7   Gam     2
----------------
```

this is hierarchy Like:

```
            Ram
             |
       --------------
       |            |
      Sham         Cam 
       |            |
    ---------       ---
    |       |       |
   Dam     Gam      Eam
```

I want how many Workers are working under particular Person Like (under Ram  2 Persons are working)

Like Ram has id =1 and we will check in Uid, and all users which are having Uid=1 will be work under Ram

Output:

```
------------------------------------------------
Id  Name   Count(Number of Employee Working)   |
1   Ram       2                                |
2   Sham      2                                |
3   Cam       1                                |
4   Dam       0                                | 
5   Eam       0                                | 
6   Fam       0                                |
7   Gam       0                                |
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please tell us which DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems like you only want to know the number of direct children not traversing the subtree in greater depth, you can try:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.name,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM elbat t2
               WHERE t2.uid = t1.id) count
       FROM elbat t1;
```

Comment: ,Thanks Can I do it with another method like CTE(Common Table Expression)